# Cannot connect to WiFi or Ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I've been having a WiFi connection problem on my Dell Windows 8.1 laptop for some time now. I know it's not a problem with the Wifi because my other devices (Mac laptop, another older Windows 7 laptop, 3 smartphones, etc.) can connect to the Wifi without any problem. I looked at the Device Manager and found so many network adapters.

[image]

I'm extremely positive that there shouldn't be as many adapters here. Also in the Network Connections, there are 8 Local Area Connections, once again pretty sure that's not how things should be.

[image]

To be honest though, I think I have a virus.

I am here to answer any other questions or things you would like to know about this problem.

Comment: What are the symptoms of your wifi problem? Are you unable to connect at all, or do you experience poor performance, frequent disconnections, or something else?  If you think you have a virus, there are programs such as [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](https://www.malwarebytes.org/) that you can run for free which shouldn't conflict with your existing antivirus software, since the free version doesn't attempt to provide real-time protection, but only on-demand scanning capability.

Comment: Cannot connect to wifi at all. I had a proper paid anti virus before but ever since it expired about 5 months ago, I got too lazy to even get a free one.. Now I can't download anything since I can't go on the internet..

Comment: Just checked .. I actually have Avast anti-virus but since I haven't been on the computer for like 2 months, I can't update the anti-virus.

Comment: Since you have a wired network adapter in the system, can you connect the laptop via network cable to your router to check on whether the problem is restricted to the wireless connectivity? I.e., does the wired network connection work fine?

Comment: hey, nope, wired doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Have you tried connecting from "safe mode with Networking" - i do not know if it its there for Win8.1. But you can give it a try to ensure that your hardware working.Next step would be to try a Linux Live CD to see how the Wireless and wired networks work on them - this will zero-out the OS issue

Comment: okay, i will try that tomorrow, and respond

Comment: Does the Wired or the Wireless adapter have a static IP configuration applied?  Right click on adapter and click Properties, go to TCP/IPv4 properties and ensure that everything is set to Obtain Automatically.

Comment: @Ol' Reliable, as Prasanna suggested, you can boot from a Linux Live CD/DVD and see if you have any network access from it. Since you stated you may have a virus and I've seen some malware cause network access issues, I'd suggest using a Live CD from an antivirus vendor, so that you can also check for malware. E.g., [F-Secure Rescue CD](http://support.moonpoint.com/security/antivirus/f-secure/rescue_cd_3-16.php), [AVG GNU/Linux Rescue CD](http://support.moonpoint.com/security/antivirus/avg/rescue-cd/version120/), [BitDefender Rescue CD](http://download.bitdefender.com/rescue_cd/), etc.